# Auto start application after boot completed in Android

Tags: android-intent, broadcastreceiver, autostart, android

I want to make an application which has auto start option in its settings. I have made Settings activity in my application which is derived from PreferenceActivity and give CheckBoxPreference for auto start option. If auto start option is enabled my application should start when booting of phone is completed. And if auto start option is disabled then it should not start on boot completed.

**To achieve this I have implemented derived class of BroadcastReceiver which receives BOOT_COMPLETED intent, declare receiver in AndroidManifest.xml and also give permission in AndroidManifest.xml.**

**In application also there is a derived class of Application and start service also from the onCreate method of application derived class.** If I declare receiver in AndroidManifest.xml then after booting completed onCreate of my application called and after that onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver called.

**Now the problem is that my application starts on boot completed every time whether auto start is enabled or disabled. Is it possible to not start application when auto start is disabled ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the shared preference to store a Boolean value for `isAutoStartEnabled`, and check this value in the BroadcastReciver, fire an intent only if it's true.

In your case, the problem is not whether you receive the broadcast but who receives the broadcast. Best of luck..

I hope it helps..

Comment: but after booting completed, first my onCreate of my application derived class is called before call onReceive of broadcastreceiveer. It means my application is created or started. But I don't want to start application if auto start is disabled.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your manifest file ?, I think the problem may lie there...

Comment: Please make sure that in you manifest file the intent filter for BOOT_COMPLETE is not with your Activity tag but with your Receiver tag.

Comment: Ya. it is in receiver tag. Application receives Boot completed intent every time perfectly, so there is no problem in manifest file. I don't want to receive it every time.

Comment: Did you check that is the activity that is started on BOOT_COMPLETE is registered to receive the BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast ?

Comment: Yes. But it is not the problem. please read the question again.

Comment: In your case, the problem is not whether you receive the broadcast but who receives the broadcast. Best of luck..

Comment: I have exited app if auto start is disabled. But to check flag and receive Boot_completed intent, it is necessary to start application (App automatically started to receive BOOT_COMPLETED intent).

Answer (score 6):

I think from **Android 3.1 onwards** your BroadcastReceiver which receives `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent its not going to work. User have to in-wake the application by interacted with it.

So, After booting the device all third party application are lying as a stop.

And for currently your application you can use `SharedPreferences` for Auto-Start your application..

**UPDATE:** (*Only for Android version below 3.1 for higher version it works but you have to user interaction with your application after boot completed on device*)

You need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` with `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` intent.

Add following to your manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name="App_Receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**App_Receiver class implementing BoradcastReciever**. Implement the `onReceive()` method and start your favorite activity from your app.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // make sure you receive "BOOT_COMPLETED"
// Here isAutoStartEnabled check sharedPreferences for Auto Start flag
if ( isAutoStartEnabled ) {

    if ((intent.getAction() != null) && (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")))
    {
        // Start the service or activity 
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently I already read flag of auto start using SharedPreference. But how to possible to not start application when auto start is disabled ? Can you give answer in detail ?

Comment: I have written that it is already implemented in application. And it works perfectly, but i don't want to receive intent every time because it starts application every time. Is it possible to not receive boot completed intent at every time ?

Comment: No, If you register any broadcast receiver then when any action make on device for that broadcast then you have it, You can't control after register it.. Just use on your condition..

Comment: Use files for save settings. And check them in your Auto Start Recever.

Comment: @user370305 The "update" is a bit misleading as it doesn't mentioned whether it also makes it work on Android 3.0+ or only Android 2.x. I suggest you clarify it in the answer, otherwise users might think the update solves what you mentioned in your first sentence of your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

You have to add the uses-permission `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` in your Manifest.

Answer (score 1):

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Application", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isAutoStartEnabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isAutoStartEnabled", false);

        if ( isAutoStartEnabled ) {
            startActivity(new Intent());
        }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: In application there is service also which starts in background when application is created, there is not only activity in application.

Comment: From Settings when you deselect the checkbox, In SharedPreference set "isAutoStartEnabled" value to false otherwise make it true. And In Boot Complete check the "isAutoStartEnabled" value from SharedPreference.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```java
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";  

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Log.d("boot completed", "boot completed caught");
            Boolean autoRestart = false;
            SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            autoRestart = sp.getBoolean("autoRestart", false);

            if (autoRestart){

                Log.d("boot completed", "auto restart true");

                Intent i = new Intent(context, WelcomeScreen.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);

            }
        }
    }

}
```