# when switch on the mobile i want to send alert message to given email in android

Tags: android, email, alert

I have a project of getting the new mobile number of theft mobile.
I this project I am doing if someone had stolen our mobile we can find that through if that person getting off our sim and he putting new sim. Then once if he switches on the mobile with new sim that particular number should be send to given email id?

Is there any possibilities?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [BroadCastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Here's an intent action for reboot that you can use: [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED).

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8950854/645270) has more on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can ! You use an On Reboot Receiver.

```
android.intent.ACTION.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Register a receiver for that action & in the onReceive method of broadcast Receiver get the telephone number of the new sim & email it to the desired email id.

I would rather send a SMS than an email because you cannot be sure the user will have internet

Hope this helps !