# Start App Firstly in Android

Tags: android, xml, startup, tablet

I wrote a code in android about bluetooth programming.I want that when I opened the tablet The app start firstly.The tablet must be specific to an application.

How is it possible ?

Comment: You can use `service`. See the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start your app as soon as the user starts the tablet, then user atleast should've opened the application once after installation. Then you can use `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` action and register a `BroadcastReceiver` to start the application automatically everytime the user reboots the deive. See [Auto start application after boot completed in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950854/auto-start-application-after-boot-completed-in-android) and [Broadcast receiver not working in ICS if the app is not started atleast once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952562/broadcast-receiver-not-working-in-ics-if-the-app-is-not-started-atleast-once). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a home screen/launcher app is the way to go.

```
<activity android:name="Home"
            ...
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"** - makes your application a home screen(launcher) app.
You can view the home screen sample from android-sdk samples/Home

Answer (score 0):

You can add in Manifest file

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
      </intent-filter>
```

to the main Activity declaration. Then you should set your app to always run as default