# How to send notification even if app is killed

Tags: java, android, android-background

I am working on an Android project that has a part which dose this:
1) the user enter a data from a data field and save it in a text file
2) the app should send notification even if the application is killed by the os, at that date, the one wrote by the user.

For example:
I write 31.01.2015

The app will notify my only on 31.01.2015 even if i don't open that app anymore.

The question is how do i have to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to have your application launch a `Service` that runs in the background even if your app is not. Alternatively, you can use an `Alarm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a notification to be posted to the notification bar.

If so I advise using an [alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

However, chances are if this is days in the future, the phone may be shut off. So you should store when the alarm should go off, create a Broadcast receiver for the [on boot complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950854/auto-start-application-after-boot-completed-in-android) event (this requires a permission), and re-setup the alarm when the boot is complete.

This should allow the notification to appear, independent of the apps life-cycle, as long as the app is not uninstalled.

Note: You will have to calculate the milliseconds between the date for the alarm, and the current time. [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) should help.

Comment: Thank you Sir. So i don't need a service or something like that if i use Alarm?