# How to avoid auto restart android app?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am new in android development.I had created an android app.Sometimes it unfortunately force closed and restart automatically.Now I want to avoid restart my app ? Is it possible ?Please help me, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The android system does the restarting.. You don't have much control over it.. Try fixing the *force close* problem  instead of preventing restart..

Comment: search in google and stackoverflow and ask questions. It may be duplicate.see below link...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950854/auto-start-application-after-boot-completed-in-android