# android broadcastreceiver auto start on boot up

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My `AndroidManifest.xml` contains:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">   <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> </intent-filter> </receiver>
```

and **MyBroadcastReceiver**

```
class MyBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MainService.class));
        //Toast.makeText(context, "    O    ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle("OK")
        .setMessage("OK")
        .setPositiveButton("ㅇㅇ", null)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .show();
    }
}
```

BUT,

I can not see the **AlertDialog** after reboot.

I launched the application many times too...

How can I make **broadcastreceiver** autostart after boot up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto start application after boot completed in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950854/auto-start-application-after-boot-completed-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to show an `AlertDialog` from a `BroadcastReceiver`, which isn't allowed. You can't show an `AlertDialog` from a `BroadcastReceiver`. Only activities can display dialogs.

You should do something else, have the `BroadcastReceiver` start on boot as you do and start an activity to show the dialog.

Add the following Activity to your application

```
public class AlertActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("OK")
            .setMessage("OK")
            .setPositiveButton("ㅇㅇ", null)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .show();
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to add the new activity to your manifest.

Then you just need to start the activity in your receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    context.startService(new Intent(context, MainService.class));
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, AlertActivity.class));
}
```

If this answer was helpful, please click the checkmark under the like button to indicate so.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast receiver cannot show dialog. Start an activity instead.